# How to add constraints to label?

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, anchor

so i created an array and placed it into a UILabel and now i want this label to stick to the top. but searching through the net this is all i could come up with:

```
let currentWeek = Date()

let weekDays = UILabel.init()
weekDays.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 65, width: 414, height: 25)
weekDays.text = "\(currentWeek.day())"
self.view.addSubview(weekDays)
weekDays.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
weekDays.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
weekDays.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
weekDays.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

according to some guide this set of constraints was supposed to make my label stretch to fill the whole screen.
but even tho i didn't get any error warnings, it did't change the appearance of my label either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of `weekDays` as `false`, i.e.

```
weekDays.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

> A Boolean value that determines whether the view’s autoresizing mask
>   is translated into Auto Layout constraints.
>
> By default, the property is set to true for any view you
>   programmatically create. If you add views in Interface Builder, the
>   system automatically sets this property to false.

And add the `height` `constraint` to `weekDays` instead of the `bottomAnchor`, i,e.

```
weekDays.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
```

Comment: @vacawama Right. Updated that. Thanks.

Comment: oooh, thank you very much hope you have a great day/night.

Answer (score 0):

Set the *translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints* of weekDays *false*.

```
weekDays.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

Comment: Longer, more detailed answers are better. Explain your answers in future to improve them. Remember: you're writing to humans, and humans need little things like that.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 ok, I will do that. Thanks for suggestion.